# How to add a simple hyperlink to images using JQuery Wrapper

Tags: jquery, hyperlink

I'm not a coder and I need a simple solution to adding a hyperlink in an html document to jQuery images ..

the following does not work so I guess it's more complex that the following ...

```
<div class="slider-wrapper">
                    <div class="slider">
                        <ul class="items">
                          <li> <a href="http://url/index.php"><img src="images/slider-img-name.jpg" alt="name" /></a>
                          </li>
```

Is there an easy way to make this work?

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to achieve here. What do you mean 'jQuery images'? Why does the above code not work for you? What jQuery code are you using?

Comment: What are you trying to do? What's a "jQuery image"? And what about the above doesn't work? [edit]Like what Rory said =]

Comment: <script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: the images are slider jpeg files - see http://www.omega.ge/

Answer (score 0):

This should work, you just need to add as many links as you want but bear in mind that for each img you must have a corresponding link, otherwise the code will fail

```
<script>
    var links = new Array();
    links[0] = "http://www.google.com";
    links[1] = "http://www.yahoo.com";
    links[2] = "http://www.bing.com";

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.items a').each(function(){
            index = $(this).parent().index();
            $(this).attr("href",links[index]);
        });
    });
</script>

<ul class="items">
    <li> <a href=""><img src="images/slider-img-name.jpg" alt="name" /></a></li>
    <li> <a href=""><img src="images/slider-img-name.jpg" alt="name" /></a></li>
    <li> <a href=""><img src="images/slider-img-name.jpg" alt="name" /></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi ALfonso, I'm assuming the script code goes after                         <div class="slider">

Comment: or does the script belong somewhere else? (as I said I am not a coder)

Comment: Well it doesn't matter, but it's better if you put it inside your <head> tags

Comment: Thanks Alfonso, I'm testing from my desktop as FTP access is limited and the hyperlinks do not work?

Comment: Is there any way you can publish the whole code so I can have a look?

Comment: Firefox on OSX ? Also tried of Safari, Chrome and Opera on OSX and does not work - what browser are you using?

Comment: just checking on IE8 (Windows 7) still not hyper links?

Comment: I've tried in many browsers and it works. Could you describe the process? Mine is as follows: Open the page, then click on the left hand side images and it opens correctly according to the array you created. Is that correct?

Comment: no, those images are static (not in Jquery slider) the images I want to link are the main large images in source code after

Comment: <div class="slider-wrapper">
                    <div class="slider">

Comment: Well you should've said that from the begining. The images are changing and the code is handled by TMSlider which build the slider and the navigation. Unless you tweak the code it won't work. If you send the link where you downloaded the script I can have a look.

Comment: Whoops sorry, thought I did? Can't find the link - is there another way?

Comment: Unfortunately the only way is by tweaking that code or perhaps looking at the documentation to see if that's supported by parameter

Comment: Found the link to FREE template it's based on .. http://www.templatemonster.com/free-templates/free-website-template-food-delivery-jquery-slider.php