# jQuery UI droppable: How do I insert a hyperlink into droppable image?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-ui-droppable

Using jQuery UI droppable code.I want to insert a hyperlink into droppable image. My code is totally similar to original code.
[droppable](https://jqueryui.com/droppable/#photo-manager)

I've tried insert hyperlink element into li element,but doesn't work.

```html
<ul id="gallery" class="gallery ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix">
      <li class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-tr">
        <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9376559/how-to-add-a-simple-hyperlink-to-images-using-jquery-wrapper"><!-- I put hyperlink here. -->
          <h5 class="ui-widget-header">High Tatras</h5>
          <img src="create_thumb.png" alt="The peaks of High Tatras" width="96" height="72">
          <a href="create_thumb.png" title="View larger image" class="ui-icon ui-icon-zoomin">View larger</a>
          <a href="link/to/trash/script/when/we/have/js/off" title="Delete this image" class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash">Delete image</a>
        </a>
      </li>
...
</ul>
```

I want droppable image can be clicked and have hyperlink function.

Comment: Your best bet is probably to add another button to the bottom of the images, the droppable stuff depends on the click event and is overriding the default click of the `a` tag. You are going to have all sorts of problems if you try to implement a click handler on something that is droppable.

Comment: the mouse can only do one (drag) or the other (navigate).